# C++ - Insert multiple integers without space separated in one line

Tags: c++

I want to insert multiple integer values less than 10.
Example:

> 010011

Each digit of above integer inputs is treated as single integer value.

I've tried this:

```
int i=0, j=0;
int arr[10000];
char temp;
do {
   scanf("%d%c", &arr[i], &temp);
   i++;
} while(temp != '\n');

cout<<endl;
for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
  printf("%d ", arr[j]);
}
```

But this code won't accept multiple integers in one line if it's initiated with 0(zero). How to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: care to explain the downvotes?, if it's duplicate just show me.

Comment: `%d` will read a whole number, not just a single digit.

Comment: You should read one character at a time. If it's a digit, convert it to a number and store in the array. If it's a newline, stop the loop.

Comment: You could also use `getline()` to read the whole line into a `std::string` at once. Then just loop through the characters in the string.

Comment: It should be integers without any conversion operation, @Barmar

Comment: There's no way to read integers one digit at a time. You have to read them as characters, then convert them.

Comment: yes, there's a way, but it should be separated with space, so the input is 1 2 0 2 1, my question is how to input them without space separated them. Thank you btw.

Comment: @Barmar You can do all sorts of wonders with scan code modifiers. Limiting the number of characters read is one of them.

Comment: done, using @KlasLindbäck answer

Comment: Be interesting to see how you handled parsing to the end of the line, Jake. Once you have your solution coded I think it will be good for future SO users with similar problems to see what you came up with. I have a feeling it can be done with `getc` and `ungetc`, but that's clunky as <expletive deleted>. Gotta be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a (maximum) length for a scan code. To read a single-digit `int` you can use the following:

```
scanf("%1d", &arr[i]);
```